# como faço para salvar a entrada de dados permanentemente

Tags: c, banco-de-dados

Eu quero criar um programa em C em que o usuário digite seu nome e que este seja salvo permanentemente, mas o nome do usuário só fica salvo até o programa fechar. Como eu faço para o programa deixar os dados do usuário salvos permanentemente?

Comment: Poste seu código, assim fica melhor para ajudar vc.

Comment: Explique melhor o que você está fazendo.

Comment: Você precisa salvar os dados em um banco de dados?

Comment: Duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105344/como-eu-fa%C3%A7o-o-meu-programa-em-c-ter-uma-mem%C3%B3ria-permanente-isso-%C3%A9-poss%C3%ADvel

Comment: Seja mais claro. Poste seu código. Caso nenhuma das respostas dadas até agora seja aceita tente reformular a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

A biblioteca stdio.h possui funções para criar, ler e escrever em arquivos txt, assim você pode manter esses dados registrados.Tenta dar uma pesquisada sobre o assunto. Aqui está um exemplo:

```
#include<stdio.h>

FILE*arquivo;
char nome[20];

int main()
{
    arquivo=fopen("exemploTXT.txt","w");
    printf("Nome: ");
    gets(nome);
    fprintf(arquivo,nome);
    fclose(arquivo);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar criar um ponteiro que escreva em arquivos. Para isso, tente o seguinte:

```
FILE *arq = fopen("endereço_do_teu_arquivo", "w"); //Esse parâmetro w significa escrita (write)
```

toda vez que for salvar seu dado no arquivo especificado, faça o seguinte:

```
fprintf(arq, "%d", dado); //Isso se o dado a ser salvo for do tipo inteiro.
```

No final do programa execute o comando:

```
fclose(arq) //Este comando fecha o arquivo salvo
```